# How to read udp packets in php

Tags: udp

I want to access the data for creating webservice in php. But unfortunately, this data is in udp format inside a LAN. I dont know how to read udp packets in php. Is there any other alternative, can udp packets be accessible via some url or it has to be converted to http to be accessible on internet? Please help